# Adding to generic lists through forms in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics

i am currently working on making a shop program in C# The problem i am having is adding  my products to a basket/checkout generic list. I have made a seperate class called Cart as you can see here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment3_New
{
    public class Variable
    {
        public static Stock shop = new Stock();
        public static Cart checkout = new Cart();
    }
}
```

I then used the Cart class as seen here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment3_New
{
    public class Cart
    {
        private List<Product> basket = new List<Product>();

        public Cart()
        {

        }

        public List<Product> returnCart()
        {
            return basket;
        }
        public void addBasket(Product tmpProduct)
        {
            basket.Add(tmpProduct);
        }

        public void deleteBasket(int index)
        {
            basket.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
}
```

After this i then proceed to my actual form and when im here my aim is that i want to be able to click on one of the products in my shop as seen in this image here >>> http://gyazo.com/832aa83758feda0019f990e01ee400a8 and click the "Add product to basket button" and on this event it should then be entered into my basket generic list which is shown in this image >>> http://gyazo.com/63c4b16f840e8f472c57adc53f223b31

I have tried to get it working but i cant get it too call the selected product into my basket, if it is needed i will attach the code for my actual basket below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assignment3_New
{
    public partial class ViewBasket : Form
    {
        public ViewBasket()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void fillListbox()
        {
            lstBasket.Items.Clear();

            foreach (Product tmp in Variable.checkout.returnCart())
            {
                lstBasket.Items.Add(tmp.Display());
            }
        }


        public void addToBasket()
        {
            lstBasket.Items.Clear();

            foreach (Product temp in Variable.checkout.returnCart())
            {
                lstBasket.Items.Add(temp.Display());
            }
         }

        private void btnCheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form PaymentForm = new PaymentForm();

            //Display the new page
            DialogResult selectedButton = PaymentForm.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void btnExitBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        } 

        private void ViewBasket_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addToBasket();
        } 

        private void btnRemoveBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(lstBasket.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                Variable.checkout.deleteBasket(lstBasket.SelectedIndex);
                fillListbox();
            }
        }

        private void lstBasket_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the amount of code here but help with my problem would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance,
Jason

Comment: You can't currently. Your code doesn't associate a listbox item with a product. Therefore, the only way for you to match them is by name.. which isn't ideal. You will need to re-think how you're displaying your items.

Comment: 'Variable.checkout' will always return a brand new instance of the Cart class, so making a call like "Variable.checkout.returnCart()" is the same as saying "(new Cart()).returnCart()", is that what you want?